# How do I wire two barrel jacks together in parallel?

Tags: pcb-design, parallel

I am quite new to electronics, and especially PCB Design. I want to have two barrel jacks for DC input to my circuit, wired in parallel, but want clarification on my circuit design. The idea is that the amps will increase, to power an ATMEGA64, as well as motors, sensors, etc. more effectively.

Here is a drawing of what I think the circuit should look like. Please provide feedback.
[image]

Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: As a general rule you cannot parallel power supplies.  There are specific exceptions, but with such a generic input format you have little way of knowing if what will be used will be one of the rare legitimate ones.  In short, this is unwise.

Comment: Consider what will happen if one supply voltage is higher than the other. Consider what will happen if one power supply plug gets pulled out.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Do you know what alternatives might be?

Comment: The right thing to do is to purchase an appropriate power supply for your project.

Answer (score 2):

> *I want to have two barrel jacks for DC input to my circuit, wired in
> parallel, but want clarification on my circuit design. The idea is
> that the amps will increase, to power an ATMEGA64, as well as motors,
> sensors, etc. more effectivel*y.

Seperate the two power circuits; use one for the motors and the other for the MCU and sensors. Keep the noisy heavy current stuff on one supply and the micro and sensors on the other. You can't rely on paralleling power supplies because usually one supplies most of the load with the other only stepping in to support the other when it begins to sag and that isn't something you really want to happen.

They should, of course, both share the same 0 volts.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that terminal 3 of the jacks is the switch contact - you definitelly DO NOT want to connect that to Ground - you would short the power input if only one supply is connected.

Another concern is whether the two supplies you are using will work happily together to share the load.  If the supplies are slightly different voltages, the higher voltage supply will provide most/all of the current.